# find out real numbers $x$ for which $f'(x)=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f'_n(x).$

Tags: real-analysis

> Q. Consider the sequence of real-valued functions $\{f_n\}$ defined by $$f_n(x)=\frac {1}{1+nx^2}.$$ Assuming the fact that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to a function  $f$ find out real numbers $x$ for which $$f'(x)=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f'_n(x).$$

My answer  is :   $x \in R$,then $f'(x)=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f'_n(x)$

Is it correct?  Please give me hints/solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't $f$ have to be continuous?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen  ya  f will not continious  on$ x= 0$

Comment: which means that the convergence cannot be uniform (or the domain in question is not all of $\Bbb R$)

Answer (score 1):

You know that $(f_n)$ converges to a function. Can you see what the function is by letting $n\rightarrow \infty$? From there can you find $f'$? Then do the same for $(f_n')$ to get an idea of how this sequence behaves.

Comment: There is no content in this answer.

Comment: Sometimes showing how to get an answer is better than giving the answer.

Comment: I don't see your point: The idea is to get what $f(x)$ is like - from then you deduce that it is discontinuous at $0$, hence this is your problematic point. You can find $f'_n(x)$ and you can similarly show that you get pointwise convergence to $0$ which is $f'(0)$. Those were the $4$ hints I gave and they are all you need. I thought they were sufficient

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x \neq 0$} \\
1, & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}$$ is discontinuous.

so, $x$  must  be belong $(-\infty,-a) \cup (a,+\infty)$  where $a \neq 0$ and $a>0$.